# Avoid circular dependencies: replace import for events?

Tags: javascript, es6-modules, circular-dependency, circular-reference

I'm splitting one file code into multiple ones and I run into a few circular dependencies.

Some of them, I am able to avoid them by refactoring a bit, others it seem more complicated or it just wouldn't make sense to me as the refactoring will probably mean having to put a lot of code together in the same file instead of splitting it by features/functionalities.

I've seen other components using events to communicate between modules and I thought I could use this same technique to avoid the circular dependency, but.... I'm not sure if this is just an ugly hack rather than the proper way of doing it.

So, for example, having the following:

```js
import { sayHi } from 'introductions.js';

export function demo(){
    // stuff here
    
   sayHi(stuff); // circular dependency here 
}
```

I was thinking I could replace it for the following:

```js
export function demo(){
    // do stuff here
    
   emit('sayHi', stuff); // event here, avoiding the import 
}
```

```js
//introductions.js
import { whatever } from './whatever.js';

on('sayHi', function(stuff){
   sayHi(stuff);
});

function sayHi(stuff){
   console.log("Hi " + stuff);
}

...
```

Would this be a proper solution to it?
Or just an ugly hack to "remove" the circular dependency?

Comment: There's nothing wrong with circular dependencies, and ES6 modules support them properly. If your code did work when it was all in one module, it will continue working if placed in multiple modules.

Comment: "*Would this be a proper solution to it?*" - yes, this is basically the [publish-subscribe pattern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Publish%E2%80%93subscribe_pattern). But you can only use it where it actually makes sense - notably that `sayHi` does not have a return value; that `demo` doesn't care when there is no subscriber, and that `demo` can cope with there being multiple subscribers.